# 405 Method not allowed using Resteasy and ajax

Tags: html, ajax, resteasy, wildfly-10

I am facing an issue while login . Registration is working fine.
Tech stack - `HTML/AJAX/JQuery->Resteasy (Wildfly 10.1.0 Final)`

I have the url - `https://www.test.com/login.html` - (actual URL name is modified)

When I am submitting the form with method type = `"POST"`, it always throws, 405 Method not allowed.

Below is the section of the code:

```
submitHandler: function(form) { // fires only when form is valid
    var loginData  = formJSONLoginData();
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://"+getUrl()+"/curAuthService/curAuth/authenticateUser/v1",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: loginData,
        success : function(response) {
            },
        error: function( xhr, status, error ){
            }
    }); 
return false;
},
```

And the Rest API is below:

```
@Path("/curAuth")
public class FHAuthResource {
    @POST
    @Path("/authenticateUser/v1")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String authenticateUser( AuthVO authVO ) {
    }
}
```

It would be great help if someone can help/advice on where I am going wrong.

Registration is in similar format and it works fine.

Comment: I don't know resteasy at all but that sounds like the CORS preflight failing. Do you have anything handling OPTIONS on that route?

Comment: But the same thing is working as is in registration page.That's where I am getting deviated from CORS.
No I have not specifically mentioned as OPTIONS

Comment: Alright, just throwing spaghetti at the wall. (You also need CORS-handling if the api is on another port)

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
We have the jquery.min.js loaded from some other url but the same again is in registration page which works fine.
The port is also same for all the services

Comment: You *also* need CORS-handling making requests cross protocol (http/https). There, I'll go away now. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimate stupid mistake. Missed out "extends Application" for the Application file which is required for resteasy.